# How to submit one html input to multiple iframes?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, target

I have an `input` in my `html` website. And three `iframe`s with different names. I want to target the url being submitted in the input to be the `src` of all those iframes. How to do this? Please help.

Comment: What did you try? Please show us some code...

Comment: I'm confused...  So you're saying you have a form, and you want the HTTP request to be sent to all the iframes on the page when the form is submitted?

Comment: loop through the frames and change their urls. it will work